# Работа с кавычками с++

Tags: c++

Допустим у меня есть строка -

```
string str = "hello      \"world\"      \"\\\\\"\"  ---   \'\\ test \\\"\' world ";
```

и мне нужно узнать откуда начинается кавычка и где она заканчивается с учётом экранизации и прочего?

Comment: А в данном примере где она начинается и где заканчивается?

Comment: тут несколько, 1: \"world\" , 2:  \"\\\"\" 3:  \'\ test \\"\' (я это сделал поскольку с этими строками основные проблемы)

Comment: Будет проще, если вы скажете, что конкретно не понимаете. В книге/гайде, по которым вы изучаете С++, не написано как ведет себя `\\` в строках?

Comment: Смотрите допустим есть строка - "\"" и что-бы мне узнать где располагаются кавычки (не экранированные ) я в цикле делал проверку что если в какой-то момент ты найдёшь \' или \" то пропусти и ищи кавычку дальше ,но если я пишу - "\\" то он считает неверно.Ладно я с этим разобрался(стал проверять что находиться за \ ) ,но если я пишу - "\\\"" то опять он считает неверно,мне понятно почему ,однако как мне сделать решение данной проблемы я не знаю .

Comment: > допустим есть строка - "\"" и что-бы мне узнать где располагаются кавычки (не экранированные )  - если у Вас есть строка, а в ней - кавычки, как же они могут быть не экранированные?

Comment: Ах извините я забыл упомянуть что строки я беру из файла ,а строки при выводе получаются такими  которые я упоминал в комментарии "Смотрите допустим..."

Comment: @Daneil Все проще. Если находите символ `\\`, пропускаете один следующий символ (не важно, кавычка это, еще один слеш, или что-то еще). Если вы наткнулись на кавычку (не пропустив ее) - это начало или конец строки.

Comment: Я так тоже пробовал вот пример ошибки при таком решении - "\\" с первой кавычкой он справился ,а с другой нет итог такого решения: " (он нашёл только одну)

Comment: Не понял. Первая кавычка - начало строки. Потом слеш, так что мы пропускаем следующий символ (который тоже слеш). Потом кавычка - это конец строки.

Comment: ААААА я идиот !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! надо было переменную цикла повышать на 1 ,а я!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
for (size_t q=0; s[q]; ++q)
  if (s[q] == '\\')
    ++q;
  else if (s[q] == '"')
    printf("Unquoted quote at %z\n", q);
```